# How to run X10 program with Sockets backend?

Tags: x10-language

I am working on a project, in which, a part is to send message from one process to another which are running on different machines. (I have to code it in X10 language).

From this [link](http://x10-lang.org/documentation/practical-x10-programming/x10rt-implementations.html), I figured out that, we can send message between processes which are running on different machines by running the X10 program with sockets backend (Please correct me if I am wrong). But I am not sure how to do it.

Can someone please tell me how to pass/send message to another process which is running on different machine with an example?